# How to add two Foreign keys from same column in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am new in Database field and My database is **MYSQL**. I have two tables (customer & transaction) which **ID** column in customer table is Primary key and
transaction table has sender & receiver columns.
    I want to make sender and receiver columns Foreign key which are references from **ID** in customer table.
    If it is possible, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Yes, you can use a primary key of one table in other table as foreign key two times.*

**you can do in this way.**

first foreign key constraint for sender column

```
ALTER TABLE transaction
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_sender
FOREIGN KEY (sender)
REFERENCES customer(ID)
```

Second foreign key constraint for receiver  column

```
ALTER TABLE transaction
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_receiver 
FOREIGN KEY (receiver)
REFERENCES customer(ID)
```